# How do we calculate the time of the beginning of audio recording from microphone using Web Audio API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio-recording, web-audio-api

How do we calculate the time (as an offset to `performance.timing.navigationStart`) of the beginning of audio recording from microphone using Web Audio API (`AudioContext/ScriptProcessor`) in Javascript?

With the term "beginning of audio recording", I refer to the `audioTimeStamp` shown in the figure below. How to calculate it?

[image: how to calculate audioTimeStamp?]

Such `audioTimeStamp` should be associated to the beginning of the audio input stream (whose samples are processed by handling the `onaudioprocess` event) in the same way a `mousedown` `event.timeStamp` is associated to the action of pressing the mouse left button.

To test the correctness of the calculation of `audioTimeStamp`, let us now suppose a "thought experiment" as an ideal scenario: we produce a sound impulse EXACTLY the same time when we click the left mouse button. Let us suppose the sound impulse is found at the i-th sample of the audio buffer, so that its time can be calculated as `impulseTimeStamp = audioTimeStamp + 1000*i/ audioContext.sampleRate`. The error can be quantified as `audioDelay = impulseTimeStamp - mousedown.event.timeStamp`: the more correct the `audioTimeStamp` calculation, the lower the `audioDelay` we get.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. I mean you write the data in a file from a stream from the microphone. Can't you log then when first time audio data appears in the stream?

Comment: @KilianHertel, my goal is to minimize/compensate hardware/software latencies. I added some text to the question to discuss a way to test the calculation of `audioTimeStamp`. According to your idea about logging the time when the `onaudioprocess(e)` event is called the first time, we can log `audioTimeStamp1 = performance.now()` or (maybe a better solution) we can calculate `audioTimeStamp2 = e.timeStamp - 1000*e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0).length / audioContext.sampleRate`. Which solution is better to minimize `audioDelay`?

Comment: Did you hear about currentTime? I think it is very hard to help you without a working example where we can see that delay... I mean I normally don't think about hypothetical stuff. Do you have any practical approach?

Comment: @KilianHertel, yes of course: `audioContext.currentTime` starts from zero as the `audioContext` is created. More, the following holds within the audio data callback: `onaudioprocess.event.playbackTime = audioContext.currentTime + numberOfSamplesReadUpToNow / audioContext.sampleRate`. However, again I do not have a precise reference to `performance.timing.navigationStart`.

Comment: @KilianHertel, pratical approach: my app should link mouse events to audio data, with the best time precision. You can find my minimal demo [here](https://www.adatec.it/apps/ProvaAudioRec2/), where source code is very simple. Currently the `audioTimeStamp2` solution provides a delay which is device-dependent (+/- 0.020secs on quadcore windows pc, +/- 0.050secs on hexacore android asus tablet). Again I would like to know which is the CORRECT way to calculate the `audioTimeStamp`.

Comment: There is a [`baseLatency`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/baseLatency) property which may be helpful in this case (not entirely sure what you ask though). There is also a `outputLatency` property too but that has no support at the moment it seem. You can also use a [offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start) value with `start()`.

Comment: `AudioContext` also has its own [`currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/currentTime).

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the example you provided. Please try to keep it as minimal as possible to the problem. You might get click latency on linux machines. But that has to do with chrome on linux. I don't now if it's fixed yet. I don't know what you mean with performance.timing.navigationStart. You need to get out of your little world and make it accessible to other people. Like this I think no one will understand what you need.

Comment: Click latency on linux could be the problem.

Comment: A solution would be to wait three seconds until recording starts. So you can sync the two processes together. It depends on how and when you want to use the software. You should be able to orientate yourself with audioctx.currentTime => this value i always right so if you have it on onAudioProcess it would be easy to determine later when audio started. so you already have the time when audio started. I don't understand what else you need. Perhaps you make the audio cutable later for the costumer, so he can erase glitches from the beginning.

Comment: @epistemex: [baseLatency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/baseLatency) is currently available in Chrome and not in Firefox nor IE/Edge. It can be used (as I do) for correcting the estimation of my `audioTimeStamp`. Again, this **does not** provide any information about the time of beginning of audio recording since `performance.timing.navigationStart`

Comment: @KilianHertel: in javascrtipt, `performance.timing.navigationStart` is the time origin for all events which occur after page loading. It is about to be replaced by `performance.timeOrigin` which is more accurate (see [time specification level 2](https://w3c.github.io/hr-time/#dom-performance-timeorigin). Please note that all events' timeStamp (`event.timeStamp`) now should refer to this common origin.

Comment: @epistemex: regarding your comment to `audioContext.currentTime`, please see my comment reply to KilianHertel (the fourth from top).

Comment: so when does your audio start recording? On Pageload or on mouseclick?

Comment: @KilianHertel: my audio recording starts on page load but, sorry, this is not relevant. Indeed, even I can issue the start of recording in a given time, the audio recording mechanism may take a bit to begin (hardware/software delay, buffering, etc...). I would like to know how to get this information (the beginning of audio recording) from the `AudioContext/ScriptProcessor`, which can be aware of such delay.

Comment: at the onAudioprocess context.currentTime is the right value